# What are the options for running custom css and javascript files on a page?

Tags: pages, css, javascript

To include custom css and javascript within a blog post or a page, one option would be to embed a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/), [codepen](http://codepen.io/), or [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/) link. In cases where you wanted to include external libraries like angular.js, d3.js, etc., these code editors and environments would provide a nice sandbox (both from a css and a js perspective) to embed in a Post or a Page.

Are there better options available and native to wordpress for creating custom pages where you have complete control over what css and js files get included in a Page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WordPress built in functionality `Function Reference/is page` and attach a `if` statement in your `script_enqueue()` function in your `functions.php` file.

Read more in the Codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Here's an example from a theme I'm building:

```
if (is_page( array('mortgage-calculator', 'contact' ) )){
            wp_enqueue_script('angularjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/angular.min.js', array(), '1.4.1', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('d3', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/d3.min.js', array(), '10/22/2015', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('c3-js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/c3.min.js', array(), '10/22/2015', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('c3-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/c3.min.css', array(), '10/22/2015', false);
            wp_enqueue_script('fcsaNumber', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/fcsaNumber.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('mortCalcApp', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/mortCalcApp.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
    }
```

These files will only be used on these two pages.